# Criação de View com limite de registos

Tags: oracle, view

Quero criar uma `view` que apenas deverá retornar um máximo de `X` registos, **independente das cláusulas de seleção aplicadas**. Ou seja, qualquer que seja o filtro que aplique, o número de linhas deverá ser sempre `X`. (com o `ROWNUM <= X` não me parece que funcione pois assim o resultado dos registos da cláusula "where" será inferior ao X porque os dados serão restringidos primeiro ao universo no âmbito do `ROWNUM <= X`).

Comment: E se o filtro for restritivo a ponto de não voltar qualquer registro?

Comment: Os registros são selecionados pelas restrições do filtro e após isso retorna o número de registros especificado pela condição ROWNUM, se houver registros suficientes.

Comment: Se fizer um select por fora ?

Comment: Select por fora não resultou. Eu quero é que retorne sempre os tais X registos e com o ROWNUM na criação da view e com o filtro no select, os registos que retornam, são menos que os que efetivamente existem.

Comment: Exemplo prático: tenho uma tabela cujo um dos atributos é o NOME dos funcionários; esse NOME faz parte da view que criei; qualquer query que eu faça a essa view deverá retornar no máximo 10 registos; passando a solução pelo ROWNUM < 10 e executando um select restringindo o nome aos "Pedros", o resultado será os " Pedros" que existem nos 10 primeiros registos, mas eu queria que retornassem 10 "Pedros" (e na tabela existem muitos mais).

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE V_VIEW AS SELECT COLUNA1,COLUNA2...FROM (SELECT COLUNA1,COLUNA2 FROM TABELA ORDER BY COLUNAN) WHERE ROWNUM < 1000

Comment: O problema é que não dá para usar o "order by". Se restringir no query outra coluna que não a "COLUNAN" não resolve o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Usando [Analytic Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions) , cria-se um rank e ordena-se por ele , a view vai em cima disto.

```
    SELECT primeironome, Ident, Nome, Dt.Nasc, Local
FROM
(
SELECT a.ID AS Ident, 
       B.NOME AS Nome, 
       SUBSTR(TRIM(NOME),1,INSTR(TRIM(NOME),' ')) primeironome,
       TO_CHAR(DATNASC,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Dt.Nasc, 
       LOCRESID AS Local,
       dbms_randam.value( vl_alea
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY primeironome  ORDER BY vl_alea)  rank 
FROM IDPESSOAL
) WHERE RANK < 11
```

Comment: Não consigo aplicar a sua solução. Se fosse possível ser mais específico agradecia. Um caso prático: tabelas "TABIDENT" e "TABBIOG"; view CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW IDPESSOAL AS  SELECT a.ID AS Ident, B.NOME AS Nome,  TO_CHAR(DATNASC,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Dt.Nasc,
  LOCRESID AS Local FROM TABIDENT a,TABBIOG b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID; A ideia é que qualquer que seja o query à view "IDPESSOAL" retorne apenas 10 registos. Por exemplo: select * FROM IDPESSOAL
  where NOME like 'A%';
  
select * FROM IDPESSOAL
  where LOCRESID like 'A%';
  
select * FROM IDPESSOAL
  where DATNASC > '1980-01-01';

Comment: "**TABLE_NAME**", "**COLUMN_NAME**" ?????!!!!! "**FROM IDPESSOAL**"Não entendi!!! E o "cliente final" só poderá fazer query's simillares aos exemplos que indiquei "Por exemplo: **select * FROM IDPESSOAL where NOME like 'A%'...**", etc e não a última abordagem que me indicou.

Comment: Editada...................................

Comment: O valor do "rank" dá sempre 1.

Comment: Só deve existir 1 neste agrupamento , creio não ter entendido como você quer agrupar. O que se dizer com "Pedros" ?

Comment: Na minha tabela "TABBIOG" existem por exemplo 500 pessoas com o nome "Pedro"; se eu fizer: select * from idpessoal where nome like 'Pedro%' quero que retornem somente 10; para todos os outros atributos que podem ser pesquisáveis (id, datnasc, local) tem de acontecer o mesmo (retornar apenas 10 registos). O utilizador final só pode interrogar a view "IDPESSOAL" desta forma "select *  from idpessoal where ....."

Comment: Testei esta solução (em outra tabela) e funcionou.

Comment: O "rank" já funciona mas não resolve pois quase sempre serão retornados variedade de atributos filtrados. Assim, serão retornados à mesma mais de 10 registos (o que não queremos que aconteça). E mais, como disse anteriormente não evita a criação de várias views e/ou querys e caso o exemplo dado seja um dos querys disponível para o utilizador final, nada me garante que ele não o altere.

Comment: Coloquei um random , deve funcionar e gerar aleatório